# Wifi works only after abrupt shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, shutdown

Its a weird thing but wifi on my Ubuntu only recognised wifi of my home router after I abruptly shutdown using my power button. Before that, It only shows 2 wifi names, not of my home wifi or wifi through my mobile hotspot. I've tried reinstalling os, updating everything, restarting network manager, resetting it, removing powersave option from wifi. None have worked. Only when I abruptly shutdown my system, does it works. This is afffecting my system as I have to do this everytime I boot. Sometimes its good for a couple of boots but thats the limit.
PS: Wifi works fine on dual booted windows

Comment: Sounds like the firmware of your WiFi device does not get correctly initialized without a power cycle. I'm a bit surprised that you didn't add any information on your WLAN hardware not your version of Ubuntu to your question, please edit it to include that! (Don't just comment)